# iTunes search query URL?

Tags: iphone, url, itunes

I'd like to make a URL that searches my name in iTunes. Basically, clicking on it should open up iTunes with my name in the search box and the results should be loading or loaded.

How do I make this URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very useful article about [iTunes links](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/)